# Need to Import the data from MongoDB to PowerBI using python Script

Tags: python, powerbi, pymongo

to load the data from mongo DB to PowerBI
we have 3 options

1. by using Mongo  ODBC connector
2. MongoDB  to python and then run same python script in PowerBI
   to load the data from MongoDB to PowerBI.
   3)MongoDB  to R and then run the same R script in PowerBI
   to load the data from MongoDB to PowerBI.

I am using 2nd method currently. I need perfect code to load data from MongoDB cloud to python.

so that I can run the same code in PowerBI.

pls help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: import pymongo
import dns

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as md
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.zev7c.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")


cursor=client.study.college.find({})
for doc in cursor:
    print (doc)



I can run this code in python. but when i run the same code in powerbi the data is not showing.